# Python pass arguments of base class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, arguments, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a subclass, Square of tkinter.Canvas, on which a line will appear when left clicked. I've got that part working, but when I try and pass width and height into my Square Class, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tictac.py", line 16, in <module>
    square = Square(master=root, width=200, height=200)
  File "tictac.py", line 5, in __init__
    super().__init__(master, width, height)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I've run into similar problems before, where "self" is being passed in as an argument. Is that what's happening here? Could someone please explain to me how this works?

The code is below, it works as I want if I remove all references to width and height, obviously other than being the width and height I want.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Square(tk.Canvas):
        def __init__(self, master=None, width=None, height=None):
                super().__init__(master, width, height)
                self.pack()
                self.bind("<Button-1>", self.tic)


        def tic(self, event):
                """"This will draw a nought or cross on the selected Square."""
                self.create_line(0, 0, 200, 100)


root = tk.Tk()
square = Square(master=root, width=200, height=200)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word in that error is "positional". You are passing arguments as positional that should be passed as keyword arguments. Change this line:

```
super().__init__(master, width, height)
```

to

```
super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height)
```

As a side note, the call signature for `Canvas.__init__` is:

```
__init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw)
```

So the three possible positional arguments are `self` (provided automatically when calling a bound method), `master` and `cnf`. Where `master` and `cnf` are optional.

Comment: Thank you, I understand.